# Open source torrent client in C#

Tags: c#, open-source, bittorrent

I'm looking for an open source implementation of a torrent client written in C#. I found some old posts on this site as well as online, but I wasn't able to see anything that works as of now. Any clients you know of?

Answer (score 11):

Do you bother if it's written in C# or not? Go for [MonoTorrent](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/tree/master/src), fully accessible from .NET.

Comment: I found the answer. I'll remove the comment.

Comment: They created a official repository for MonoTorrent https://github.com/alanmcgovern/monotorrent

Answer (score 6):

Try [MonoTorrent (discontinued)](http://www.mono-project.com/Bitsharp) .

Comment: BitSharp is the old name of Monotorrent